# I am getting an authenticator error in my React Native project

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am using React Native alongside AWS authentication/AWS Amplify. I am trying to implement a confirmation page on my app, that once the sign Up button is pressed on the page, it sends the information to AWS and navigates to a confirmation page. HOWEVER all my implementations are giving me the same error "username can not be empty".

```
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp(
    email = string,
    password = string,
) {
    try {
        const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
            username: email,
            password,
            attributes: {
                email,
            },
            autoSignIn: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}

export function SignUpPage() {
    const route = useRoute();

    const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    async function onSubmit(data) {
        const user = await signUp(data.email, data.password)
        console.log(data);
    }
```

I tried generating a random string as the username value and then updating it once the user submits his login information, but that led me to the problem of the console reporting that the password field must not be empty. I am at my WITS END!!!